# Two Separate Row Level Security Rules for 1 Role

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

In setting up Row level security, I am trying to have two filters, each for a separate table, for one role. Currently, I have two tables: Projects (listing all projects, owners, location and start/end dates) and Project Time (listing all projects, employees, time spent, and date. Both tables are have a relationship connected by Project ID.

I am setting up roles and have users that need access to their time spent but also data for Projects in locations they are assigned. For example, the user would see their time and all other employees' time spent on projects in their location. However, the separate filters are just compounding and the user can only see their hours spent on projects in their location. The following are the DAX expressions I have for their filters. Please confirm if this achievable via dax and not adding a separate column for emails.

User1:

- Table1 - Project table:  [Location] = "NYC"
- Table2 - Project Time table:  [Employee] = "User 1"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers the question directly, but I would approach this as follows.

Create **two** roles (one for location and one for employee) and assign users to both. The end users should be able to see data according to all roles they are assigned.

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. But unfortunately, this didnt work. Individually, the roles work but then when both are viewed for some reason a lot more things than allowed are shown. For example, employee role shows 2k hours, location shows 5k, but combined I get a total of 11k hours and other locations and employees are viewed, weird enough. I tihnk I might just include the location field in the project time table also to save some time.